# Find item in a list starting with a user specified letter

Tags: python

Im trying to make a program where I already have a list that is being read from a .txt file and now I need to make it so that when I give Python my "desired letter" it will put all my items that start with that letter into another list.

thanks in advance

```
countrypopList = open("E:\\SCRIPTING\\Countries.txt").readlines() #This is     making "countrypopList" contain everthing on the txt.
countrypopList.sort() #This is sorting the list alphabetically.
useriList = []
countries = []
population = []
userI = input("Please input a single letter: ") #Ask user to input a single     letter.

if userI.isalpha():
    if len(userI) > 1:
        print("Please enter only a single letter.") #If user input length is     over 1, display this message.

    else: #If there are no complications and the user inputs a single letter     as required, the program continues.
        #print("continue")
        for line in countrypopList:
            if (line.startswith(userI)):
                useriList.append(line)

    print(useriList)            
else:
    print("Please make sure that you enter a single letter.") #If user     inputs anything other than a letter with a length of 1, display this message.
```

This is what I thought of at first but it didnt work and I dont know where to go with it..

Comment: "it didn't work" is inadequate description of a problem. Please describe the problem you are having. See [ask].

Comment: use `.startswith` method of `str`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for this:

```
text = open('data.txt').read()
user_letter = raw_input('Please enter one letter: ')
starts_with = [word for word in text.split() if word.startswith(user_letter)]
```

Comment: `word` is in fact each individual character

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your list from a text ready,you can then call it to this function with your user input and list:

```
def startString(char, userlist):
    ls = []
    for string in userlist:
        if string.startswith(char):
            ls.append(string)
    print(ls)

startString(userI,yourList) #call fuction on your data(userinput and your list from text)
```